# $or operation for matching the same element in two different arrays

Tags: mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have two different arrays in two different documents, namely `carPolicies[]` and `paPolicies[]`. Evidently, there are `policy` objects containing a key of `agent`.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "_id",
    "name": "qwe",
    "password": "pw",
    "carPolicies": [
      {
        "policy": {
          "agent": "47"
        }
      },
    ],
    "paPolicies": [
      {
        "policy": {
          "agent": "47"
        }
      },
    ]
  },


  {
    "_id": "_id",
    "name": "rty",
    "password": "wp",
    "carPolicies": [
      {
        "policy": {
          "agent": "47"
        }
      },
    ],
    "paPolicies": [
      {
        "policy": {
          "agent": "47"
        }
      },
      {
        "policy": {
          "agent": "99"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I do a query such as I have below, it will return me the policies only from `carPolicies[]` where `agent`: 47.

```
db.collection('users').aggregate([
    
             
    
            // get just the documents that contain an agent key where agent is  === 47 
            { $match: { 'carPolicies.policy.agent': req.params.name } },
            {
                $project: {
                    policy: {
                        $filter: {
                            input: '$carPolicies.policy',
                            as: 'police',
                            cond: { $eq: ['$$police.agent', req.params.name ]}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        
        ])
```

However, I would like to modify the same query to check `paPolicies[]` where `agent`: 47 also. How would I add an `$or` to be able to check both arrays in one query where `agent` is 47? Or is there another operator that fits my use case more?

My expected outcome should output:

```
[
  {
    "policy": [
      {
        "agent": "47"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "policy": [
      {
        "agent": "47"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "policy": [
      {
        "agent": "47"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "policy": [
      {
        "agent": "47"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

There should be 4 policies in the output since in my example, only 4 policies have `agent` = 47 where one of the policies have an `agent` = 99 which should not be retrieved.

Comment: where you want to add `or` condition in $match or $filter ?

Comment: @turivishal what do you mean?

Comment: i mean where you want to check condition for `paPolicies`? in $match pipeline or in $project pipeline filter?

Comment: @turivishal preferably in the $match pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- add condition in `$match` using `$or`
- add `paPolicies.policy` as input in filter using and `$concatArrays`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `policy` array
- `$project` to convert `policy` as array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "carPolicies.policy.agent": req.params.name },
        { "paPolicies.policy.agent": req.params.name }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      policy: {
        $filter: {
          input: {
            $concatArrays: ["$carPolicies.policy", "$paPolicies.policy"]
          },
          as: "police",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$police.agent", req.params.name] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$policy" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      policy: ["$policy"]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kCtOTg6yTvl)

Comment: I checked your mongo playground link, it didn't retrieve policies from the `paPolicies[]` where `agent` is 47 as you can see from my code, I've got a `$filter` where `input` is `$carPolicies.policy` specifically. What if you do it in the `$filter` instead?

Comment: yes thats why i asked you, can you add your expected result form your data

Comment: sure, I'll add it in my question for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Just a question, how do I modify the query to $match a user's _id also?

Comment: something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/iyKZDW5Iwks

Comment: It works in the mongo playground but in my app, I keep getting an empty array. But if I remove the _id, I get results.

Comment: what is the field _id value inside document? its string number, or number or its mongo object id?

Comment: ObjectId. But what I do is this `{_id: ObjectId(req.params.id)}`

Comment: my `req.params.id` is correctly getting the _id of the user.

Comment: you need to verify the _id is same id that you have in collection and check its object id or string object id in collection.

Comment: Yep, I have. I've already fixed the problem. I needed to explicitly add in my query that the _id is an objectId.